If $g(x) = \sum_{j = 0}^{m}g_{j}x^j ~\&~ v_{p}(g(\alpha)) = v$ for all root of $f(x)$. Then can we claim that $p^v \mid g_j\alpha^j$?
Let $f(x), g(x) \in \Bbb{Z}_{p}[x]$(where $\Bbb Z_p$ is the set of all $p$-adic integers). Also, assume that $f(x)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n$ and $g(x)$ be any polynomial of degree $m \geq n$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$.


If $g(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{m}g_{j}x^j$ and $v_{p}(g(\alpha)) = v$ for all root $\alpha \in Z(f) = \{x: f(x) = 0\}$. Then can we claim that $p^v$ divides each $g_j\alpha^j$? That is $v_p({g_j\alpha^j}) \geq v$ for all $j$.(Here we know that $g(\alpha) = p^v \hat{g}$, where $v_p(\hat{g}) = 0$)
If $r(x) = g(x) \bmod{f(x)} = \displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{n-1}r_{j}x^j$, then can we claim that $p^v$ divides each $r_j\alpha^j$?


First of all, for question 2 it is clear that $r(\alpha) = g(\alpha)$, for all $\alpha \in Z(f)$. So $v_{p}(g(\alpha)) = v_{p}(r(\alpha)) = p^v$, hence $p^v$ divides $r(\alpha) = \displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{n-1}r_{j}\alpha^j$. Can we say that $p^v$ divides each of $r_j\alpha^j$, that is $v_p({r_j\alpha^j}) \geq v$ for all $j$?

This equality holds iff $v_p(x_i) \neq v_p(x_j)$ for $i \neq j$

No. Consider $p=2, f(x)=(x-1)^2, r(x)=x+1, g(x)=f(x)+r(x)$.

Maybe you can add more on how this observation answers the question?

@ТymaGaidash: It says the answer is "no" to both questions by providing a counterexample for both claims. I seriously don't understand what more one could elaborate, except for spelling out each coefficient and its valuation, which I'm sure anyone who understands the question can do. Or do you want me to add that the zero set of $f$ consists exactly of $\alpha=1$?

Thanks @Torsten Schoenberg for the answer.
